# Express a cyclonic force field as a differential 1-form

Tags: multivariable-calculus

From Second Year Calculus (by David Bressoud)

Q:
Consider a cyclonic force field circling the z-axis in a counterclockwise direction with a strength inversely proportional to the distance from the z-axis. Show that this force field is described by the 1-form: $$c\left(\frac{-ydx}{x^2 +y^2}+ \frac{xdy}{x^2+y^2}\right)$$ for some constant c.

My work:
I know the distance from the z-axis is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

So, $|\vec{F}| = \frac{k}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ for some proportionality constant k.

Now, I don't know how to model the cyclonic direction of the force field.

In short $$\vec{F} = \frac{k}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\vec{r}$$ Where r is a unit vector.

I don't know what $\vec{r}$ is.

r could be the slope of the force field. But for that, I should know what the equation of our force field should be but I don't even know how it might look.

Comment: Hint: What is $|\vec{F}|$ when
$$
\vec{F}=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\begin{pmatrix}-y\\x\end{pmatrix}\;?
$$

Comment: Thanks for your response! Actually, now that you give me a hint as to what the force field could be it seems somewhat trivial given that the differential form is already given. But my question is how would we come up with this? It must connect with the cyclonic nature of the field. How does it connect?

Comment: Draw a picture. I don't think there is a mathematical definition of cyclonic field.

Comment: Yeah, I get it it's just hard to visualize

Comment: Write down a vector field tangent to circles centered at the origin in the $xy$-plane.

Comment: See [irrotational vortex](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorticity#Examples).